# Error: XMLHttpRequest error - Sending data from flutter app to Nodejs Server

Tags: node.js, express, flutter, flutter-web, body-parser

I am trying to send JSON formatted data to my Nodejs server and getting the above error.
My flutter side code is as follows:

```
http.Response response1 = await http.post(Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).getsubmitOrderURL(), body: { 'Order': Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).getOrder().toString() }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: (){
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Error communicating with the server'), duration: Duration(seconds: 2)));
  return;
});
```

My server side code is as follows:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser= require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const https = require('https');

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/receiveOrder", function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body.order);
  res.sendStatus(200);
  return;
)}
```

Resulting error:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
```

This is my first time programming my app with a server involved. Need help please to figure out the solution.

Comment: getting the error on which side client or server, elaborate on this error

Answer (score 0):

So after a few hours of experimenting. I figured out the error was due to CORS policy. I added app.use(Cors()) on my node side and installed CORS prior to this. It’s working fine now.